# What are some good ways (or the best way) to blend many (10+) textures or materials together on a single mesh?

Tags: shaders, transparency, texture-painting, shader-nodes

**I'm creating terrain for a landscape with 10+ different materials on a giant mesh with millions of vertexes and a single giant displacement texture: Why isn't it working perfectly? /s**

**But really, lets say that for some reason I'm forced to do it this way - a single mesh. I have a bunch of PBR materials and each has a corresponding alpha mask like this:**
[image]

**Currently I just have one material, and I have a bunch of principled shaders linked together in series with Mix Shaders and the alpha masks as factors:**

[image]

While it sort of gets the blending that i want, problem is that after the 7th or 8th mix shader I can no longer preview the material or see it in eevee and instead have to preview it rendered in cycles. Also swapping the position of these textures in the stack is kind of clunky.
So again, I'm wondering if there is a better way to stack many materials/textures... Or if there is a just a more elegant way mixing textures.

vertex colors? geo-nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as below. The example has four textures but shows the idea.
[image]